# loop code is not working with mysql and php data?

Tags: php, mysql, api, twitter

I am trying to make a retweet app.
I have the access token and access token secret of 200 twitter accounts
I tried to make a loop to get all the users access token and sercret to retweet one tweet but its not working.

```
    <form action="<?php echo  $PHP_SELF;?>" method="post">
    <input type="submit" name="do"value="do"></input>
    </form>
    <?php
    // twitteroauth
    require_once('twitteroauth.php');
    mysql_connect ("localhost","___","___");
    mysql_select_db ("___");
    $do=$_POST ['do'];
    $consumerKey = '___';
    $consumerSecret = '___';
    $tweet = new TwitterOAuth($consumerKey, $consumerSecret, $accessToken, $accessTokenSecret);
    $doo=" SELECT * FROM users";
    $users=mysql_query($doo);
    foreach ($users as $value) {
       $accessToken = $value['users_oauth_access_token'];
       $accessTokenSecret = $value['users_oauth_access_token_secret'];
    }
    if(isset($do)){
       foreach($tweet as $retweet) {
          $retweet=$tweet->post('statuses/retweet/437294293233836032');
          print_r($retweet);}
       }
    }
    ?>
```

Comment: Could you be any more specific than "its not working"? And please clean your code up. Are you sure that it's `$$accessTokenSecret`?

Comment: I typed the extra $ by accident.

Answer (score 0):

First you have to fix line with *$$accessTokenSecret* and remove one $ sign.

You don't retrieve anything from database, because you are just send a query. So after using *mysql_query()*, you should use one of the *mysql_fetch* functions. After this check what have you get by using *print_r()* or *var_dump()* function and write proper loop.

**EDIT:**

```
$doo= "SELECT * FROM users";
$queryResult = mysql_query($doo); 
$users = mysql_fetch_assoc($queryResult);

foreach ($users as $user) {
    $accessToken = $user['users_oauth_access_token'];
    $accessTokenSecret = $user['users_oauth_access_token_secret'];
}
```

I hope you have this fields in your *users* table. But I don't know what are you want to do next with your variables, so I just rewrite them from your code sample.

Comment: I dont know how to do that, can u please edit the code for me :)

Comment: the foreach loop doesn't make sense. the tokens will be overwritten each time.

Comment: @hellcode can u show what should I put instead of foreach please :)

Comment: I know, but it's taken from provided code sample. I don't know how he want to use it later.

Comment: guys please tell me what should I put instead of foreach

Comment: Foreach is OK, but I don't know where you want to use variables $accessToken and $accessTokenSecret of each user.

Comment: I want each user to do connection on $tweet and do this code $tweet->post('statuses/retweet/437294293233836032');

    print_r($retweet)

Comment: So you have to put the code below first foreach in this foreach.

Comment: Please use the mysqli library at least as mysql is deprecated